# How to pivot data in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, pivot

I've a table which contains text data containing a bunch of translations for different language. Each translation is for a specific label.

I need to generate a pivot table so to get quickly what's missing.

An example of the records is

```
1, en, hello
1, fr, bonjour
1, es, hola
2, en, how are you
2, fr, 
3, es, come es stas
```

Although translations should be always there for all language, I'm not 100% sure this is the case. So missing fields have to be considered.

The desired outcome is this

```
|ID|EN|FR|ES|
|1|hello|bonjour|hola|
|2|how are you| |come es stas|
```

The challenge I have is that the column order may not always be the same when the database is populated, so in theory I should have a dynamic list of fields.

There is not a direct PIVOT function in SQLite, so I started experimenting with the group_concat obtaining a comma separated string.

```
SELECT DISTINCT language, group_concat(word, ',') OVER (PARTITION BY language) AS group_concat
FROM vocabulary;
```

I can ran past the results later on in Python if needed; the issue is that any missing value is not appending an empty item thus shifting all the concatenation by n, thus making this solution not valid.

I have attempted also to use the filter clause in the select predicate (though this mean hardcoding the columns), but I was not able to succeed.

Any idea on how this can be achieved?

Comment: [This enterprising fellow](https://github.com/jakethaw/pivot_vtab) has implemented pivot as an sqlite extenison.

Comment: Sounds promising, though the *_id might be confusing at first

Answer (score 3):

I was able to arrive to a semi-satisfactory solution, though the only thing missing is a dynamic column selection.

```
SELECT id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN "language" == 'it' THEN word END) as 'it',
       MAX(CASE WHEN "language" == 'en' THEN word END) as 'en',
       MAX(CASE WHEN "language" == 'ru' THEN word END) as 'ru'
FROM (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by language order by id) as seq
      from vocabulary t
     ) t
GROUP BY t.seq;
```

Regrettably SQLite doesn't support dynamic queries, so these have to be constructed via the callee, in my case a Python script.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have dynamic columns in a pivot table in SQLite. You'll have to use extensions, though.

The first option is to use dynamic SQL and the `eval(sql)` function from the [define](https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean/blob/main/docs/define.md) extension.

Create the schema and load data:

```sql
create table phrases(phrase_id integer, lang_code text, phrase text);

insert into phrases(phrase_id, lang_code, phrase)
values
(1, 'en', 'hello'),
(1, 'fr', 'bonjour'),
(1, 'es', 'hola'),
(2, 'en', 'how are you'),
(2, 'fr', null),
(2, 'es', 'come es stas');
```

Build and execute a dynamic query that creates the `v_phrases` view:

```sql
with langs as (
  select distinct lang_code as code
  from phrases
),
lines as (
  select 'drop view if exists v_phrases; ' as part
  union all
  select 'create view v_phrases as '
  union all
  select 'select phrase_id ' as part
  union all
  select ', max(phrase) filter (where lang_code = "' || code || '") as "' || code || '" '
  from langs
  union all
  select 'from phrases group by phrase_id order by phrase_id;'
)
select eval(group_concat(part, ''))
from lines;
```

Query the view:

```sql
select * from v_phrases;
```

```
┌───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬──────────────┐
│ phrase_id │     en      │   fr    │      es      │
├───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1         │ hello       │ bonjour │ hola         │
│ 2         │ how are you │         │ come es stas │
└───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴──────────────┘
```

The second (and probably simpler) option is to use the `pivot` extension. See [Building a Pivot Table in SQLite](https://antonz.org/sqlite-pivot-table/) article for details.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will return all IDs that do not have all translations:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM vocabulary
GROUP BY id
HAVING count < (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT language)
                FROM vocabulary);
```

If you want to know which languages are missing for each ID, use a [compound query](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) to look up those languages that are in the list of all languages but not in those for this ID:

```
WITH missing_ids AS (
  SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM vocabulary
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING count < (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT language)
                  FROM vocabulary)
)
SELECT id,
       (SELECT group_concat(language)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT language FROM vocabulary
              EXCEPT
              SELECT language FROM vocabulary WHERE id = missing_ids.id)
       ) AS missing_languages
FROM missing_ids;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this. This actually start solving the problem. I assume that having a separate column for each of the items like in a pivot table is not possible, right?

Comment: Not automatically.

Comment: Any chance I can create a list of columns with the `with` statement and attach to the solution I posted above?

Comment: No; SQLite cannot execute any kind of dynamic SQL; you'd have to construct the query in Python.